# Limit length of string from DataGridView

Tags: string, vb.net

I am printing a `String` from a `DataGridView` value and I want to limit its character length to 20. This is the code I'm working with:

```
Dim Descripcion As String = Detalle_VDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString
```

Comment: Look for the Substring method of the string class. And please do some basic research before posting

Comment: You can set the `MaxInputLength` for a text column and if the data comes from a DB with a max length defined, the DataTable/DGV will usually pick that up...of course if printing means printing, see Steve's comment but it is usually best to fix things as far upstream as possible

Comment: Yes, I tried but I'm having errors with that value from the DataGridView. If I write a new string and use the Substring method like "limit.Substring(0,3)" it works. When I use that method with DataGridView's value I get the error 'index and length must refer to a location within the string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good thing you're using VB so you can use the old fashioned `Left`:

`Dim Descripcion As String = Left(Detalle_VDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString, 20)`

Part of `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.